# Prolog and Java with Eclipse (arch Linux)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, prolog, swi-prolog

I need to use JDK 8 and SWI-Prolog 6.6.4 for a university project and Eclipse. I installed SWI-Prolog from source and the JDK from aur. When I try to execute the example y get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/lib/swipl-6.6.4/lib/i686-linux/libjpl.so: /usr/local/lib/swipl-6.6.4/lib/i686-linux/libjpl.so: undefined symbol: __gmpz_init

the path is where `libjpl.so` is... I've been in google for like 2 hours and cant resolve it.

Comment: Solved with this tuto http://www.codecompiling.net/node/137

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that you built SWI-Prolog without GMP support. Make sure that the GMP package is installed. Typically there is an end-user GMP package and one with the GMP headers. You want the later.